# Nested Subquery Too Slow

Tags: mysql, sql

The following mysql query which uses double nested subqueries is too slow

```
SELECT t.name
FROM creatives AS c
INNER JOIN term_relationships AS tr ON tr.creative_id=c.creative_id
INNER JOIN terms AS t ON t.term_id=tr.term_id
WHERE c.creative_id IN
   (SELECT creative_id
    FROM term_relationships
    WHERE term_id IN
       (SELECT offer_term_id
        FROM offer_urls))
AND t.taxonomy LIKE 'ad_network';
```

The inner query

```
SELECT creative_id
    FROM term_relationships
    WHERE term_id IN
       (SELECT offer_term_id
        FROM offer_urls)
```

is extremely fast (0.04 seconds)

but the full query doesn't deliver the results. I gave up after waiting for about 5 minutes.

Any way to optimize this?

Comment: why not try a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and a null check instead? While this next statement is pure guesswork, I'd assume that the subqueries are being executed per retrieved row (so row a, executes a subquery for all rows b, which individually execute for all rows c).

Comment: Are your tables indexed properly?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM creatives AS c
JOIN term_relationships AS tr ON tr.creative_id=c.creative_id
JOIN terms AS t ON t.term_id=tr.term_id
JOIN term_relationships tr2 ON tr2.creative_id = c.creative_id
JOIN offer_urls ou ON ou.offer_term_id = tr2.term_id
WHERE t.taxonomy LIKE 'ad_network';
```

This version written only with JOINs will be much quicker.

Comment: you maybe should explain why you can leave away the where .. in .. part  :), but your solution is the same i came up with

Comment: I edited the answer a minute after posting it to add the `where`, I missed it in the copy paste

Comment: Unfortunately, this logic won't work for me. For each offer_term_id, I have many records in term_relationships table. Each record will give me a creative_id. Now, I need to do a secondary search again with each creative_id in the term_relationships table. From that data-set I will have to filter the records that have required taxonomy. I hope I made some sense here. It is very hard for someone to understand all this without looking at the tables. But thanks for your help. If you have another suggestion, please let me know. thinking of splitting the queries  and let php handle some logic

Comment: Hi @hvs I will definitively help you further if you can provide a data sample (sql format would be ideal) and an expected result. If you do that I will write your query.

Comment: Thanks @Gab for your kind offer. I have created a very basic and simple database that explains my situation on sqlfiddle. The [first link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e02422/1) is my query that delivers the desired data and the [second link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e02422/2) is your query which delivers empty dataset.     Hopefully this will give you a little bit of insight. Of course, in the actual scenario both term_relationships and creatives table are huge so the processing time for my query is unacceptable

Comment: Please select my answer as accepted if it fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting this using `exists`:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM terms t JOIN
     term_relationships tr
     ON t.term_id = tr.term_id JOIN
     creatives c
     ON tr.creative_id = c.creative_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM term_relationships tr2 JOIN
                   offer_urls ou
                   ON tr.term_id = ou.offer_term_id
              WHERE c.creative_id = tr2.creative_id
             ) AND
     t.taxonomy LIKE 'ad_network';
```

Then for this you want the following indexes:

- terms(taxonomy, term_id)
- offer_urls(offer_term_id)
- term_relationships(creative_id, term_id);
- creatives(creative_id)

You may have already defined some of these using primary key definitions.